# Write access to commandArgs?

Tags: r

I know that I can use `commandArgs` to read the command line arguments passed to a script in R, but I would like to debug a command line script by `source`ing it in R and making it run using custom command line arguments. Is there a way of modifying the command line arguments without modifying the script file?

My scripts are normally using the `optparse` package for actual argument parsing, if that helps.

Comment: Best practice would be for your "command-line scripts" to just handle the commands and then pass them to a function defined external to the script file - such as in a package. That way debugging is easier and your external code is re-usable. If you try and do everything by making one script file you will quickly wear out the cut and paste keys on your keyboard.

Comment: I absolutely agree - I have most of my code in external script files, I just don't want to re-create all parameters for calling my function within R every time something crashes when I can easily set everything I need using command line arguments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply overwriting it with your own definition, e.g.

```
commandArgs <- function(trailingOnly=FALSE) { 
    args<- c("/foo/bar", "baz") 
    # copied from base:::commandArgs
    if (trailingOnly) {
        m <- match("--args", args, 0L)
        if (m) 
            args[-seq_len(m)]
        else character()
    }
    else args
}
```

Comment: To make this work with the `optparse` package, I had to specify the `args` parameter explicitly (otherwise it would use the `commandArgs` from base): `opt = parse_args(OptionParser(option_list=option_list), args=commandArgs(T))`

Comment: Ah yes, namespaces. I'll try to amend my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try and expand what I said in a comment.

The python way of writing scripts usually involves detecting if the file is being run as a script, handling the args, and then calling functions defined in the file. Something like:

```
def foo(x):
    return x*2

if __name__=="__main__":
    v = sys.argv[1]
    print foo(v)
```

This has the advantage that you can import the file into an interactive python session and the code in the 'if' block doesn't run. You can then test the `foo` function interactively.

Now is there a way you can check in R if the file is being run as a script, or being sourced from an interactive session?

```
foo=function(x){
 return(x*2)
}

if(!interactive()){
 x = as.numeric(commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)[1])
 print(foo(x))
}
```

If run with `Rscript argtest.R 22` will print 44, if you run R interactively and do `source("argtest.R")` it won't run the code in the if block. Its a nice pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to replace `source()` with `system()`. Try

```
system("Rscript file_to_source.R 1 2 3")
```

Comment: Will debugging by using `browser()` in `file_to_source.R` still work? Edit: apparently not. Then I could just call the script from the regular command line instead of using `system` and don't really see any advantage in this approach.